# Testing universal app on iphone only

Tags: iphone, testing, ios-universal-app

I am developing a universal ios app and the iphone version is nearly done and about 50% of the ipad. However I need to get started testing the iphone version. Therefore I changed the project only to be a iphone target. However when the app is on the ipad, the nib files for the ipad version is loaded in the iphone simulator. Therefore you only see a fraction of the ipad screen in the iphone simulator. One solution is to remove the references to the ipad nib files, however I would like to avoid this approach.

Anyone one with suggestions?

Regards

EDIT: The problem is if I want people to be able to test the iphone version on a ipad(some people only have an ipad not an iphone). When running the iphone simulator on the ipad, it would load the wrong nibfiles. Those intended for the actual ipad and not the iphone.

Comment: Why did you change the project to only be an iPhone target? Why haven't you got it as a universal project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it ended up with the solution I did not want to do :) I removed the nib files intended for the ipad and it removed the issue. After the test I will have to add the ipad nib files to continue working.

Comment: Did you find any other solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to "change the project only to be a iphone target". Change it back and just build and run on the device (iphone or ipad depending upon which one you have plugged in).

Btw, in future I STRONGLY recommend that you test early and test often - e.g. test on devices every day.

Comment: I do test often, but i did it with a universal app with no problems. The problem is if I want people to be able to test the iphone version on a ipad(some people only have an ipad not an iphone). However this caused the iphone simulator on the ipad to load the wrong nib files.